# getting extra Thumbs.db file in destination location

Tags: batch-file

While i am executing the following statements:

```
for /f "Tokens=* " %%I in (' dir  /b/a-d "%src_dir%\*.*"') do  (
echo %%I>> %save_file%
)
```

i am getting Thumbs.db evrytime in my destination folder %save_file%..
Please suggest , how to exclude that .DB file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```dos
dir /b /a-d "%src_dir%\*" | findstr /v /e /i /l /c:"\thumbs.db" > %save_file%
```

Filter the lines that do not match (`/v`), at the end of the line (`/e`), ignoring case (`/i`) the literal (`/l`) `\thumbs.db` and send all the output to the indicated file.

**edited** to adapt to comments

```dos
(   for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
        dir /b /a-d "%src_dir%\*" ^| findstr /v /e /i /l /c:"\thumbs.db" 
    ') do echo %%a 
) > %save_file%
```

The only "problematic" part is the need to escape the pipe character (the reason for the `^`)

Comment: @Prakhar, wrapped in a `for` loop. The result will be the same but performance is a lot worse than the original code.